# how to stop background activity from running when an alert dialog is running in android

Tags: android, process, background, dialog, alert

I have an alertdialog with two edit texts and when a user tries to input text into one of the edit texts, a new instance of the background activity seems to be created. How do I stop that from happening?

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
    showDialog(DIALOG_SEARCH_ID);

    return false;
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {
    case DIALOG_SEARCH_ID:
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View searchView = factory.inflate(R.layout.searchbar2, null);
        AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(TravelBite.this)
            .setView(searchView)
            .create();
        Window win = ad.getWindow();
        win.setGravity(48);
        return ad;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post the code of where you are creating and handling the AlertDialog. We can't really give an answer based on your description alone.

Comment: Are you also using onPrepareDialog()? We need to see the code where you're handing the EditText input.

Comment: I'm not using onPrepareDialog() and not handling the EditText input yet. I saw the background activity running just from selecting the EditText box.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs are created asynchronously.  As in, when the engine hits

```
AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(TravelBite.this)
            .setView(searchView)
            .create();
```

it generates a call to create that, and keeps on going straight to `Window win = ad.getWindow();`.

You'll need to handle it via flags and/or more logic inside the dialog's onClick handlers.

So, when you egt the code built for handling the dialog's edittexts and buttons, paste it here  :)

Comment: Could you clarify what needs to be handled by flags or inside onClick? I edited my answer and added in the XML that contains the EditTexts and Button, but I'm not sure how the code for handling the EditText can help stop the background activity from being recreated.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the google's Android developer documentation:

> ...When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut
>   down and restarted by default...

I assume this is what's happening; the background activity is being restarted due to a device configuration change (such as screen orientation, input modes, screen size, etc.).

In your manifest file, declare that both your background activity and your AlertDialog activity handle a configuration change, i.e.:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="locale|navigation|orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

You can change the attributes for `android:configChanges` depending on your situation.

Take a look at the Android documentation and see which attributes you need:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config